# Using Rails to_xml(:methods =>) options need the method to be wrapped as cdata

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.4 and "`to_xml`" with the `:methods => option`, and I want to include a Base64 encoded thumbnail image.

Is there any way I can specify that that method needs to be wrapped in a cdata tag?

Example:

```
  render :xml => @items.to_xml(
    :include => [:photos,:comments], 
    :methods => [:encoded_thumb]) { |xml| 
      xml.tag! 'total-entries', @items.total_entries 
      xml.tag! 'per-page', @items.per_page 
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems like the "procs" option would work if was able to target the individual objects in the collection:

Eg this works:
proc = Proc.new { |options| options[:builder].tag!('encoded_thumb', @items.first.encoded_thumb) }

But would it be possible to pass in each item rather than the collection with the proc?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 you can use `Proc`:

```
encoded_thumb = Proc.new do |options, item|
  options[:builder].tag!('encoded_thumb') do
    options[:builder].cdata!(item.encoded_thumb)
  end
end

render :xml => @items.to_xml(
  :include => [:photos,:comments],
  :procs   => encoded_thumb
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be :methods => [:encoded_thumb_cdata], and wrap that method in your model.

Comment: I tried that, but it escapes the cdata tag so I end up with this type of thing: &lt;cdata&gt;  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought about that... Hmm. that's a question that deserves a +1.